# Display Custom Command Button Kendo UI Grid in MVC with Conditional Authorization Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, conditional-statements, authorization, kendo-grid

Kendo UI Grid in MVC with Conditional Au Custom Command Button
How Conditionally display Destroy or Custom Command button Base on Authorization

**I wanna display a Custom Command in kendo MVC grid For users that have Role="Admin"**
Like

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
   {
```

In my Kendo Grid

```
@(Html.KendoGrid<Management.Models.Users.UserModel>("dgvUser", "PartialCustomUserModel", false)

.Columns(c => c.Command(cc =>
    {
    cc.Custom("delete").HtmlAttributes(new
   {

    @style = @"
                color : transparent;
                background-position: center center;
                background-image: url('../Content/themes/base/images/blue/imgEditUser.png');
                background-size: contain;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height: 28px;
                cursor: pointer;"
}).Click("deleteUser");
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid<YourModel>()
      .Name("Grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Command(command =>
          {
              if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
              {
                  command.Custom("delete").Click("deleteUser");
              }
          }).Title("Commands");
      }))
```

or easily, instead of adding custom button, just add the destroy button

hope this will help you

Comment: Tnx Dude...
Its helpfull.

Comment: Is there any way to link a command to a controller action or method?